# Display what is wrong with email address using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

I have an html form that requests any email.  currently, I have a php function that looks at the entry and confirms whether or not it is a valid government or military email. (This does not cover all email types.  It is pretty simple).  I'm trying to figure a way that would validate whether or not the email is valid and alert the user to what specifically is wrong with the email they entered all while using jquery.  Below is what I have thus far.

```
<form id="mil" name="mid"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" style="width: 200px;">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
<?php
function isValidEmail($email){ 
    if (filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) == true){
        if(strpos($email, '.gov') !== false || strpos($email, '.mil') !== false)
            return true; 
    } else { 
    return false; 
    }    
} 


if($_POST['Submit'] == "Submit")
{
    $valid = isValidEmail($_POST['email']);
    if($valid == false): echo "Not a government or military email";
    else: echo "Valid email";
    endif;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to validate only when user try to submit form.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/evmS9/1/)

**HTML**

```
<form id="mil" ... onsubmit="return valForm()">
```

**JS**

```
function valForm() {
    if(!$('#email').val().match(/.gov|.mil/)) {
        alert("Not Valid Email");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

With this **regex** you can completly validate the user email:

```
$('#email').val().match(/^[ -~]+@[ -~]+\.[mil|gov]+$/)
```

Comment: Are you able to display how you would break that up to show what parts are missing?

Comment: @CBC_NS, I didn't understand your question, you can check this working at the fiddle I've provided.

Comment: @Toni_Almeida Your fiddle works fine.  Do you see how you are looking at all of the segments at once?  I'm wondering how you could break it down so that you could alert the user which parts of the entry are incorrect.

Comment: You can perform multiple `if / else` statements, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/evmS9/5/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#email').on('blur', function(){
    if(this.value.indexOf('.gov') > -1 || this.value.indexOf('.mil') > -1){
        //it's valid, do nothing, or something..
    }else{
        alert('You must enter a valid Government or Military issue email address!');
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zs52x/)